# Multiple navbars: only first one displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to display to navbars in my webapplication using Bootstrap 3. I'm using following code. There are basically two sections, first one is fixed-top and second one is static-top.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Button</button>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <div class="navbar-text">Text</div>
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is that only the first one is showing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the top-value of the second navbar to the height of the first one.
My guess is, that they are overlayed and fixed one is on top.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on how to do that? Are you referring to changing a value in CSS file?

Comment: There are two options I would try:

1) Try to set the margin-top of the second Navbar to the height value of the first navbar. 

2) Set the top css attribute of the second navbar to the height of the first (fixed) navbar.

Answer (score 0):

As first navbar is fixed you need to add the padding-top to the body tag you can find the reference on bootstrap site

Body padding required
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

which specific that::

The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
Copy

```
body { padding-top: 50px; }
```